# My pitbull Julia - The biting machine

Tags: dogs, breeds

She is 2 months old and has a tendency to bite every bit of a thing.

We bought her calcium bones but that only keeps her busy for a short time.

How to reduce her such type of behaviour.
She has spent a **week** with us.

Answer (score 3):

Puppies tend to gnaw on things for various reasons.

The simplest thing is really, they don't know better. It takes time to train a puppy to know some things are wrong. A good strong no, and seperating the pup from the thing she's chewing on (and lots of positive reinforcement) for the right sort of chewing is good.

She might also be bored. Keep her engaged. Play with her. Puppies are high energy, destructive little creatures who need that energy redirected. My dog went from chewing everything he could reach to pretty well behaved once he realised people would play with him

Finally, its young enough that she's teething, and that'll pass.

Comment: Might add that puppies just like to taste things, and don't know better. Also, they don't have hands, and we humans like to look at things with our hands. Puppies just have a mouth to test things for texture.

Comment: Human babies can be bitey too.

Comment: But even calcium bones don't work. Isn't there any way I can teach her what to bite and what not?

Comment: Lots of positive reinforcement when they bite the right things, more or less. Its a *process* and not always a fast one.